# Terraform module 1 output as input to module 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have 2 terraform modules, one for Launching instance from custom AMI (AMI Backup) and another to test the status of instance (1/2 or 2/2 status) launched via this custom AMI .

I am using external data source calling the Bash script for instance status .

Can the output of module 1(instance id) be used as a input to module 2 ?as instance id is required in external module .

```
 [root@ip-172-16-1-168 devops]# vim main.tf
 module "mymodule" {
 source = "/terraform/devops/modules/AMI_Creation_module"
 qa_instance_type = "t3.medium"
 qa_subnet_id = "subnet-0ab**9a916***4cc"
 qa_key_name = "terraform"
 Environment = "QA"

 module "mymodule2" {
 source = "/terraform/devops/modules/AMI_Status_module"
 qa_instance_type = "module.mymodule2.qa_instance_type"
 qa_subnet_id = "module.mymodule2.qa_subnet_id"
  qa_key_name = "module.mymodule2.qa_key_name"
 Environment = "QA"
 #QA-server-via-ami = ["${module.mymodule.QA-server-via-ami}"]
 }
```

AMI_Status_Module :

```
 data "external" "instance_status" {

 program = ["bash", "${path.module}/get_instance_status.sh"]

 query = {
 id = QA-server-via-ami.id
 }
}

output "test" {
value = data.external.instance_status.result
}
```

Bash Script :

```
 #!/bin/bash

 set -e

 eval "$(jq -r '@sh "INSTANCE_ID=\(.id)"')"

 status=$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids ${INSTANCE_ID} --output json --query 
 'InstanceStatuses[0]')

 instance_status=$(echo ${status} | jq -r '.InstanceStatus.Details[0].Status')
 system_status=$(echo ${status} | jq -r '.SystemStatus.Details[0].Status')

 jq -n --arg inst_status "$instance_status" \
  --arg sys_status "$system_status" \
  '{"instance_status":$inst_status,"system_status":$sys_status}'
```

can we put sleep between the two modules ?as i want instance status after some time .

```
AMI_Creation_Module main.tf : 

terraform {
required_providers {
aws = {
  source  = "hashicorp/aws"
  version = "~> 3.0"
 }
 }
 }

provider "aws" {
region = "us-east-1"
access_key = "A*************"
secret_key = "k**************"
}


 resource "aws_ami_from_instance" "QA-ami" {
 name               = "QA-ami"
 source_instance_id = "i-00f4*******"
 } //line20 


 resource "aws_instance" "QA-server-via-ami" {

ami = aws_ami_from_instance.QA-ami.id
instance_type = var.qa_instance_type
subnet_id = var.qa_subnet_id
key_name = var.qa_key_name
tags = {
    Name = "QA-server-via-ami"
}
}

output "instance_id" {
value = aws.ec2_instance.QA-server-via-ami.id
}
```

Comment: How did it go with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Can the output of module 1(instance id) be used as a input to module 2 ?as instance id is required in external module .

Yes. In your `mymodule` you would need to define some output that returns the instance id to parent module, e.g.:

In mymodule tf script

```
output "instance_id" {
  value = aws.ec2_instance.<your-instance>.id
}
```

Then you pass it to the second module:

```
module "mymodule2" {
 source = "/terraform/devops/modules/AMI_Status_module"
 qa_instance_type = "module.mymodule2.qa_instance_type"
 qa_subnet_id = "module.mymodule2.qa_subnet_id"

 instance_id = module.mymodule.instance_id

  qa_key_name = "module.mymodule2.qa_key_name"
 Environment = "QA"
 #QA-server-via-ami = ["${module.mymodule.QA-server-via-ami}"]
 }
```

> can we put sleep between the two modules ?

Yes you can. There are several ways of doing this. The easiest would be to put sleep in your bash script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 set -e

 eval "$(jq -r '@sh "INSTANCE_ID=\(.id)"')"

 sleep 60 # provide how much time you want to wait. now 60 seconds

 status=$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids ${INSTANCE_ID} --output json --query 
 'InstanceStatuses[0]')

 instance_status=$(echo ${status} | jq -r '.InstanceStatus.Details[0].Status')
 system_status=$(echo ${status} | jq -r '.SystemStatus.Details[0].Status')

 jq -n --arg inst_status "$instance_status" \
  --arg sys_status "$system_status" \
  '{"instance_status":$inst_status,"system_status":$sys_status}'
```

But if you want to wait only until instance status is ok, you can use [instance-status-ok](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/wait/instance-status-ok.html):

```
 #!/bin/bash

 set -e

 eval "$(jq -r '@sh "INSTANCE_ID=\(.id)"')"

 aws ec2 wait instance-status-ok --instance-ids ${INSTANCE_ID}

 status=$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids ${INSTANCE_ID} --output json --query 
 'InstanceStatuses[0]')

 instance_status=$(echo ${status} | jq -r '.InstanceStatus.Details[0].Status')
 system_status=$(echo ${status} | jq -r '.SystemStatus.Details[0].Status')

 jq -n --arg inst_status "$instance_status" \
  --arg sys_status "$system_status" \
  '{"instance_status":$inst_status,"system_status":$sys_status}'
```

Comment: While running Terraform plan i am getting error as Error: Argument or block definition required

  on main.tf line 20, in module "mymodule":

An argument or block definition is required here.

Comment: @AnkitK Where is "here"? What is line 20? Your question is incomplete and does not provide such information. This seems as a new issue.

Comment: I have attached AMI Creation Module main.tf file above , and mentioned line 20 ,please have a look .

Comment: I have made a new question , where i am facing issue with bash scipt being called by external data source .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67104606/issue-while-calling-bash-script-using-external-data-source-in-terraform

Comment: I was testing the sleep in bash script , but getting the error .

Comment: @AnkitK What error? From the new question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231165/discussion-between-ankitk-and-marcin).