# Issue while calling Bash script using External data source in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have External data source , that is calling the bash script .

```
Main.tf : 

 resource "aws_ami_from_instance" "QA-ami" {
 name               = "QA-ami"
 source_instance_id = "i-00f4*****75**a"
 }

 resource "aws_instance" "QA-server-via-ami" {
 ami = aws_ami_from_instance.QA-ami.id
 instance_type = var.qa_instance_type
 subnet_id = var.qa_subnet_id
 key_name = var.qa_key_name
 }

 data "external" "instance_status" { //line  38

 program = ["bash", "${path.module}/check_instance_status.sh"]

 query = {
 id = aws_instance.QA-server-via-ami.id
 }
 }

  output "test" {
  value = data.external.instance_status.result
  }
```

Bash Script  :

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

eval "$(jq -r '@sh "INSTANCE_ID=\(.id)"')"

sleep 600

status=$(aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-ids ${INSTANCE_ID} --output json --query 
'InstanceStatuses[0]')

instance_status=$(echo ${status} | jq -r '.InstanceStatus.Details[0].Status')
system_status=$(echo ${status} | jq -r '.SystemStatus.Details[0].Status')

jq -n --arg inst_status "$instance_status" \
  --arg sys_status "$system_status" \
  '{"instance_status":$inst_status,"system_status":$sys_status}'
```

But when i am running terraform apply , i am getting below error :

Error: failed to execute "bash": bash: ./check_instance_status.sh: No such file or directory

on main.tf line 38, in data "external" "instance_status":
38: data "external" "instance_status" {

My bash script is present in /check_instance_status.sh , still i am getting error .

Please assist me .

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just a path problem, I'm assuming this is in a submodule? Then try `path.root` like this: `program = ["bash", "${path.root}/check_instance_status.sh"]`

Also make sure that `check_instance_status.sh` is executable with `chmod +x check_instance_status.sh` and that it runs correctly on the command line.

Comment: tried with path.root , and script have executable permission, still getting error .

Answer (score 0):

Add the complete path directly in

```
program = ["bash", "/path/to/check_instance_status.sh"]
```